# how to create robust scraper for specific website without updating code after develop?

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping, bert-language-model, scrape

I want to make a robust scraper to fetch data in specific website, and don't want to change the code with updating the site in during time,I'm looking for a way to tell to scraper to find some fields like title,description,title_url and etc... tags automatically.
how to make this scraper?
thanks.

I say this question from GPT and tell me use neural network and deep learning approches and using pretrained tools like BERT to do this, I think this problem has a simpler solution than training an AI model.